# MYSQL records count fluctuating

Tags: mysql

I just inserted ~140,000 entries into a MYSQL table and when I look at phpmyadmin, the records count looks like ~129,000 and fluctuates on every refresh.

Any ideas why it is doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpMyAdmin uses a quick method to get the row count, and this method only returns an approximate count in the case of InnoDB tables. See $cfg['MaxExactCount'] for a way to modify those results, but this could have a serious impact on performance.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faq3_11

Comment: So it's not something I should be worried about then? It's not bothering me, I just want to make sure the data is there...

Comment: you can always check with `select count(*) from table`